Issue while catching signalR response
I am encountering an issue with handling SignalR responses in my application. The setup includes a React frontend and .NET services as the backend. The API calls are made using Kafka, which subscribes and consumes requests on one thread, while the responses are processed on another thread via SignalR.
Scenario 1: When a page is already open and I make an API call, the SignalR connection successfully receives and processes the response.
Scenario 2: However, when I make an API call during the initial loading of the page (in the useEffect hook in React), the SignalR connection does not consistently receive or process the response as expected.
This is the code how I have registered the signalR at my react side.
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

class Connector {
  private url = 'https://localhost:5000/serviceGatewayHub';
  public connection: signalR.HubConnection | undefined;
  static instance: Connector | undefined;
  constructor() {
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(this.url).withAutomaticReconnect().build();
    this.connection.start().catch();
    this.connection.onclose(this.reconnect);
    this.connection.onreconnecting(this.reconnect);
  }

  public static getInstance(): Connector | undefined {
    if (!Connector.instance) Connector.instance = new Connector();
    return Connector.instance;
  }

  reconnect = () => {
    setInterval(this.startConnection, 2000);
  };

  startConnection = () => {
    try {
      if (this.connection?.state !== 'Connected') {
        this.connection?.start().catch();
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}

export default Connector.getInstance;

This is the case where I am facing issue with signalR response.
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Connector from 'src/pages/signalRConnection';

const GetPageData = () => {
  const [signalRData, setSignalRData] = useState<any>();
  const [signalRHub, setSignalRHub] = useState(Connector);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (!signalRHub) {
        try {
          setSignalRHub(Connector);
        } catch { }
      } else if (signalRHub?.connection) {
        signalRHub.connection?.off("GetDataResponse");
        signalRHub.connection?.on("GetDataResponse", async (message) => {
          setSignalRData(message.Data);
        });

        return () => {
          signalRHub.connection?.off("GetDataResponse");
        };
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://localhost:5000/getData", getHeadersForAPI());
  }, []);

  const getHeadersForAPI = () => {
    return {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        TokenSalt: 'secretTokenSalt',
      },
    };
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Data received via signalR: {signalRData}</h1>
    </>
  )
};
export default GetPageData;

In the code provided, the API is being called during the initial loading of the page. However, in this scenario, SignalR sometimes misses the response.
How can this be addressed to ensure that SignalR reliably catches the response when the API is called at the very beginning of the page load?
